# Теряется точность double числа при записи в файл

Tags: c++

При записи double числа в файл, остается лишь 6 знаков после запятой. 
В интернете нашел что кол-во знаков регулируется функцией precision(n). 
Помогите пожалуйста, как быть с синтаксисом, как правильно это использовать

```
 ofstream fout("Data.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
       fout2 << "(" << TestFunction(t*i) << ")"<< "\n";
    }
fout.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот так:

```
double d=9.123;

ofstream out("F://test.txt");

out<<setprecision(3)<<d<<endl;
out.close();
```

в вашем варианте вот так:

```
 out<<setprecision(3)<<"(" << d << ")"<< "\n";
```

ах да, еще сделать include

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Comment: А зачем дублировать **прямой** слеш в `F://test.txt`?

Comment: да в принципе не за чем, просто мне нравится чисто визуально, когда после названия диска идет двоеточие и **два** слэша